# An infinite series for tangent without Bernoulli numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac{\sin{(x)}}{\cos{(x)}} = -\frac{2x}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (\frac{\left (\frac{2x}{\pi}  \right )^2-1}{4}-(n+1)n \right )^{-1}$$

I discovered this experimenting with series using my theory of that with $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$, it is possible to construct any function and number (including divergent ones) using addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, fractionless exponentiation ($-i$ is allowed but not $\frac{1}{i}$), factorials and parentheses in the sequence and the upper limit of summation using [only one series](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1974-28-125/S0025-5718-1974-0328414-1/S0025-5718-1974-0328414-1.pdf).

Are there any other examples of this occuring, like for example with [Faulhaber's formula](https://exnumbers.miraheze.org/wiki/Main_Page#Basic_idea)?

Edit: Want to find your own series like this? Study [spurious relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship) between sequences and [voodoo programming](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voodoo_programming).

Comment: 1. Can you prove this equation ? 2. For which real $x$ does the sum on the right converge ?

Comment: @Peter: As an autodidact I'm not good at proving things yet. It seems to converge for all $x$.

Comment: Congratulations on this discovery!  As Jean's answer shows, it is already known.  But finding it on your own is still impressive.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thank you, made my day! Encouragement goes longer than people think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the formula you give is equivalent to this one

$$\pi \tan(\pi z) = 8z\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n + 1)^2 − 4z^2}$$

which is rather well known.

It is called a pole expansion (see article on [Mittag-Leffler expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem)) somehow spreading the poles of $\tan(\pi z)$ as the poles of the different fractions.

Comment: Well, thank you! Do you have an example of a Faulhaber variant before i mark you answer?

Comment: In the wikipedia article I mention there are other pole expansions.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.